# Закрытые проблемы не попадают в архив

Tags: framework, php, yii

Пусть есть экшн Архив в Проблем контроллере, хочу сделать так, чтобы все закрытые проблемы отображались в архиве и убирались из активных (т.е. те, у кого статус равен 100, то бишь тема закрыта). Проблема в том, что они убираются из активных, но в архив не попадают. Что делать? Но в самой бд они остаюся с измененным статусом.

P.S. Я новичок, не судите строго.

Comment: А, ну, все, я поняла, в чем дело: всего-то один метод надо было поменять, а я не заметила.

Comment: О боже, вы сами понимаете что пишите?

Comment: Поток мыслей, который стороннему человеку трудно понять. )